Copying dynamic array does not share same memory
I am trying to understand how the copying of the dynamic arrays work in SystemVerilog.
Here is a small code snippet I was trying:
//dynamic_array
module dyn_array();
    //2 dynamic arrays of integer type
    int dyn1[];
    int dyn2[];
    initial 
        begin
            //allocate 5 mem location to dyn1
            dyn1 = new[5];
            //populate the elements of the dyn array
            dyn1 = '{1,2,3,4,5};
                
            $display("the value of dynamic array is %p", dyn1);
                
            //copy method 
            //method1: entire array elements are deleted and copied into new array
            dyn2=dyn1; //they point to the same memory
            $display("the value of dynamic array dyn2 is %p", dyn2);
            
            //changing value of element in dyn2 
            dyn2[2] = 10;
            
            //this change will NOT reflected into dyn1. Why? 
            //Ideally dyn2 should point to the same memory location in dyn1
            //why is the change not reflected in dyn1? 
            //dyn1 = 1,2,3,4,5, dyn2=1,2,10,4,5
            $display("dyn1 after change of dyn2 is %p", dyn1);
            $display("dyn2 after change of dyn2 is %p", dyn2);
            
            //the previous elements are erased and it will create 10 locations
            dyn1 = new[10];
            //dyn1 will be empty 10 element array with 0s
            $display("dyn1 after new[10] is %p", dyn1);
            //dyn2 will be unchanged- 1,2,10,4,5
            $display("dyn2 after new[10] is %p", dyn2);
            
            dyn2 =new[10/*new size*/](dyn2); // 1,2,10,4,5,0,0,0,0,0
            $display("dyn1 after new[10](dyn2) is %p", dyn1); //dyn1 should be unchanged
            $display("dyn2 after new[10](dyn2) is %p", dyn2);            
        end    
endmodule

Here are the simulation outputs on Modelsim:
# the value of dynamic array is '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
# the value of dynamic array dyn2 is '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
# dyn1 after change of dyn2 is '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
# dyn2 after change of dyn2 is '{1, 2, 10, 4, 5}
# dyn1 after new[10] is '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
# dyn2 after new[10] is '{1, 2, 10, 4, 5}
# dyn1 after new[10](dyn2) is '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
# dyn2 after new[10](dyn2) is '{1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

I am not able to understand why after dyn2[2]=10, when I display dyn1, the print says
'{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

and not
'{1, 2, 10, 4, 5} 

on the simulator as I expect dyn1 and dyn2 to share the same memory and any change in dyn2 to be reflected into dyn1.
Could you please explain the behavior in the simulation?


I expect dyn1 and dyn2 to share the same memory

The IEEE Std 1800-2023 does not specify that 2 separate dynamic arrays, when assigned to one another, will share the same memory.
Refer to section 7.6 Array assignments:

Assignment shall be done by assigning each element of the source array
to the corresponding element of the target array. Correspondence
between elements is determined by the left-to-right order of elements
in each array. For example, if array A is declared as int A[7:0] and
array B is declared as int B[1:8], the assignment A = B; will assign
element B[1] to element A[7], and so on.

The simulator behaves as expected according to the Std.

Unlike C/C++, arrays are not treated as pointers to memory. They are aggregate unpacked array types (or dynamic collections of identically typed elements). Every place you do an assignment to a dynamic array as a whole array, you are allocated a new space for that array, and then copying each element from source to destination. This is opposed to doing an assignment to a select of an array like yn2[2] = 10; where there is no allocation.
Note that doing

dyn1 = new[5];

is not necessary before
dyn1 = '{1,2,3,4,5};

since that assignment does allocation prior to population of the array. It would be a tool optimization to figure out that the array has already been allocated to the needed size.
